# ROS Network SetUp

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, bashrc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a router IP= 192.168.1.1  ,  A PC IP=192.168.1.2, Magni IP=192.168.1.3, and a Jetson IP = 192.168.1.4

**All hosts files  on every machine are:**

```
192.168.1.2   adrian 
192.168.1.3   magni
192.168.1.4   jetson
```

I can ping and shh from all three machines.
Magni is running the master and I have the following in all .bashrc's:

**PC**

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://magni:11311/
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.2
```

**MAGNI**

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://magni:11311/
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.3
```

**Jetson**

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://magni:11311/
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.4
```

I run into a problem where when I start a roscore from the Magni it is the correct ROS_MASTER_URI  and IP. However, whenever I try to run rostopic list from both the Jetson and PC I get an  "ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!" . I have also tried exporting the ROS_HOSTNAME  instead of the IP for the Magni but that did not work either. What's confusing is that I can ping and shh into all three. I have also switched out routers as I thought it was an issue but no luck. I was wondering if anyone has encountered this before or you see any red flags in my setup.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369002/ros-network-setup/) by [adrianabeyta](https://answers.ros.org/users/60011/adrianabeyta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-01-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check whether you have a firewall active.

ICMP (== ping) is nice, but only tells you basic networking is configured. It doesn't mean *everything* is OK.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adrianabeyta](https://answers.ros.org/users/60011/adrianabeyta/) on 2021-01-06**:
I disabled the firewall and it worked! I realize disabling the firewall is not the safest thing to do. Any suggestions/resources to help with configuring the correct firewall settings?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-06**:\

> I realize disabling the firewall is not the safest thing to do

seeing as all the IPs you show are local IPs, and you probably have a NAT router between you and the internet, it won't immediately make things completely insecure, but in general: yes, disabling a firewall might not be the best solution.

> Any suggestions/resources to help with configuring the correct firewall settings?

unfortunately ROS nodes need quite a few network ports open, and they tend to open random ones (ie: not from a limited subset). Configuring firewalls for such cases is not easy.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-06**:
What you could do is configure the firewall to accept all traffic coming from certain hosts. So in this case that would be your `adrian`, `magni` and `jetson`.

Any other traffic would have to be specifically configured.

Still not completely secure, but perhaps better than disabling the firewall completely.